# Is it possible to never lose in tic-tac-toe?

Tags: game-theory, tic-tac-toe

Although it is impossible to win every game of tic-tac-toe, is it possible to never lose? Is there a specific placement or strategy for the game?

Comment: I'm 99% sure I've heard that this game will always be drawn with perfect strategy from both sides. Yes. I'm surprised you didn't find this: https://blog.ostermiller.org/tic-tac-toe-strategy.

Comment: If it was not possible to never lose, then it would be possible to always win.

Comment: The only winning move is not to play,.

Comment: War games.  Brings back memories of dialup modems. I used that line in my wifi password, much to the chagrin of guests.

Comment: [Obligatory xkcd](https://xkcd.com/832/).

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Here is a link explaining the whole thing: https://blog.ostermiller.org/tic-tac-toe-strategy.