# How to prove that there is no strategy to always win in tic tac toe

Tags: logic, game-theory, tic-tac-toe

I’m doing a game theory project and I’m trying to show the win strategies for different games but there is none for tic tac toe. However, I’m not sure how to prove it except for using experimental probability or game trees so I was wondering if there was a more elegant way to prove that.

Comment: https://www.quora.com/Is-there-a-way-to-never-lose-at-Tic-Tac-Toe

Comment: Game trees are not bad, if you exploit all the symmetries.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2582230/is-it-possible-to-never-lose-in-tic-tac-toe

Comment: An *elegant proof* is exactly a program (in Python, prolog or what-have-you) that is always able to at least force a draw (which needs to be proved). It is a compressed representation of the strategy after all.